# HTML5 Audio player only works on first mp3

Tags: php, audio

I am setting up a PHP sermon list. One form and button for each sermon. The Action page successfully catches the value of the Input and plays it. The Input type is Hidden so that it does not unnecessarily clutter up the web page. My problem is that the Action page will only play the very first sermon it receives, no matter how many other sermon Play buttons I click on. Back and forth. Back and forth. Still only plays the first sermon and ignores all the rest. Does it with every browser. Every device. Probably simple. Thanks.

Each sermon of the list has its own form and button

```
<form id="sermonform" action="sermon-player.php" method="post">
<button type="submit" form="sermonform" value="submit">PLAY</button>
<input type="hidden" name="sermon" value="2022-0904.mp3"> Just Like the Clay and the Potter
</form>
```

sermon-player.php

```
<?php
$sermon_name = $_POST['sermon'];
echo "
<audio id=AudioBox controls autoplay>
    <source src=sermons/2022/$sermon_name type=audio/mpeg>
    Your older browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your question detail you have form for each sermon which hold the sermon play button and sermon value that can be seen in your question

- Ensure that form id is unique for each form. You have posted on single form so it can't be seen if they all have same id.
- If each form have same id, submit button from each form will submit the 1st form to action script.

> `<form id="this_need_to_be_unique">`

for each form

Comment: Overlooked something simple. Thanks.

Comment: @Travel2Learn welcom! do you know how to mark as accepted answer and up vote?